# Send Email - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, email

How would I be able to send emails using Cocoa? Which framework would I use, and how would I use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple's Developer Connection has a sample project called SBSendEmail which demonstrates how to use a Scripting Bridge to send email via scripting to the Mail app.

You can download the [whole project](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SBSendEmail/) and run it in XCode to see how it works. Of particular interest to you will be the sendEmailMessage: method in [Controller.m](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SBSendEmail/Listings/Controller_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004645-Controller_m-DontLinkElementID_4)

Comment: Please note that Scripting Bridge is not allowed with sandbox app.

Comment: This isn't true; you can use Scripting Bridge with the correct entitlements

Answer (score 15):

I think using an Apple script is the simplest solutions. I use it when the user has an account set up in Mail.

Apple script:

attachments is an array of stings containing file paths.

"set visible to true" if you want the message to pop up before sending

```
- (void)sendEmailWithMail:(NSString *) toAddress withSubject:(NSString *) subject Attachments:(NSArray *) attachments { 
NSString *bodyText = @"Your body text \n\r";    
NSString *emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                         tell application \"Mail\"\n\
                         set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:\"%@\", content:\"%@\" & return} \n\
                         tell newMessage\n\
                         set visible to false\n\
                         set sender to \"%@\"\n\
                         make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:\"%@\", address:\"%@\"}\n\
                         tell content\n\
                         ",subject, bodyText, @"McAlarm alert", @"McAlarm User", toAddress ];

//add attachments to script
for (NSString *alarmPhoto in attachments) {
    emailString = [emailString stringByAppendingFormat:@"make new attachment with properties {file name:\"%@\"} at after the last paragraph\n\
                   ",alarmPhoto];

}
//finish script
emailString = [emailString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\
               end tell\n\
               send\n\
               end tell\n\
               end tell"];



//NSLog(@"%@",emailString);
NSAppleScript *emailScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:emailString];
[emailScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
[emailScript release];

/* send the message */
NSLog(@"Message passed to Mail");
```

}

Disadvantage: users need to have valid accounts under Mail.

Python Script (if no user account under mail): 
You can also use a python script to send a message. 
Disadvantage: users have to enter SMTP details unless you grab them from Mail (but then you can use the apple script above ), or you have to have a reliable SMTP relay hardcoded in your app (you can set up a gmail account and use it for that purpose, however if your apps send too many emails google can delete your account (SPAM))
I use this python script:

```
import sys
import smtplib
import os
import optparse

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

username = sys.argv[1]
hostname = sys.argv[2]
port = sys.argv[3]
from_addr = sys.argv[4]
to_addr = sys.argv[5]
subject = sys.argv[6]
text = sys.argv[7]

password = getpass.getpass() if sys.stdin.isatty() else sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = from_addr
message['To'] = to_addr
message['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
message['Subject'] = subject
#message['Cc'] = COMMASPACE.join(cc)
message.attach(MIMEText(text))

i = 0
for file in sys.argv:
    if i > 7:
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
        message.attach(part)
    i = i + 1

smtp = smtplib.SMTP(hostname,port)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(username, password)
del password

smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string())
smtp.close()
```

And I call it form this method to send an email using a gmail account

```
- (bool) sendEmail:(NSTask *) task toAddress:(NSString *) toAddress withSubject:(NSString *) subject Attachments:(NSArray *) attachments {

        NSLog(@"Trying to send email message");
        //set arguments including attachments
        NSString *username = @"my.gmail.account@gmail.com";
        NSString *hostname = @"smtp.gmail.com";
        NSString *port = @"587";
        NSString *fromAddress = @"my.gmail.account@gmail.com";  
        NSString *bodyText = @"Body text \n\r"; 
        NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    programPath,
                                    username,
                                    hostname,
                                    port, 
                                    fromAddress, 
                                    toAddress,
                                    subject,
                                    bodyText, 
                                    nil];  
        for (int i = 0; i < [attachments count]; i++) {
            [arguments addObject:[attachments objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        NSData *passwordData = [@"myGmailPassword" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSDictionary *environment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"", @"PYTHONPATH",
                                     @"/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin", @"PATH",
                                     nil];
        [task setEnvironment:environment];
        [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/python"];

        [task setArguments:arguments];

        NSPipe *stdinPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        [task setStandardInput:stdinPipe];

        [task launch];

        [[stdinPipe fileHandleForReading] closeFile];
        NSFileHandle *stdinFH = [stdinPipe fileHandleForWriting];
        [stdinFH writeData:passwordData];
        [stdinFH writeData:[@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [stdinFH writeData:[@"Description" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [stdinFH closeFile];

        [task waitUntilExit];

        if ([task terminationStatus] == 0) { 
            NSLog(@"Message successfully sent");
            return YES;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Message not sent");
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: i tried ur code but the issue is that when u launch it, it says programPath isnt defined. Now i did set it to the path of my program using NSString but still didnt work... what should i do???

Comment: It is the path of the script and defined as: programPath = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"emailSender" ofType:@"py"] copy];

Comment: i added the resource code of python on my project with name  emailSender.py. Also wrote the code  NSBundle * programPath   = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"emailSender" ofType:@"py"] copy]; 
  All errors are gone but no email is sent . Console shows these details . PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: 2012-02-15 14:42:39.897 mailSend[5582:a0f] Trying to send email message
  File "/Users/myMac/mailSend/build/Debug/mailSend.app/Contents/Resources/emailSender.py", line 1
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf350
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
2012-02-15 14:42:39.972 mailSend[5582:a0f] Message not sent
2012-02-15 14:42:39.974 mailSend[5582:a0f] mail not sent

Comment: The second solution worked very well for me, so thanks! The only issue I encountered was that the example python code needs to import getpass

Comment: I didn't even realise AppleScript existed! This helped me bridge a gap for sending emails in a Mono Mac application. For anyone interested, I used [this](http://applescriptslim.codeplex.com) nifty little library.

Answer (score 4):

You can use opening the default [mail client](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2009/03/09/how-to-send-an-email-in-cocoa/) or you can use a [framework](http://vafer.org/blog/20080604120118). This should get you started.

Comment: Both of them don't work for me. Can anyone give me an example? I'm sorry but I am very new to this?

Comment: Are you developing for the iPhone or Desktop?

Comment: I'm developing on Desktop with Xcode 3.2

Comment: You can't develop anywhere other than the desktop, if you're developing for the desktop those 2 links are well efficient if you try them out.

Comment: Also note, they both include code you can copy and paste, and run to get what you want, they will work.

Answer (score 2):

For Growl 1.2, I wrote [a Python-based mail-sending program](http://bitbucket.org/boredzo/simple-mailer), which the MailMe display runs using NSTask.

I did this largely out of dissatisfaction with the other mail frameworks for Cocoa, most of which also support receiving mail, which is unnecessary for something output-only like MailMe.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime

I haven't looked at it in several years, but when I was at Apple I advocated that we include it with the OS to replace the mail functionality we'd lost in the NeXT/Apple transition.