# How to initiate email on xcode for mac app

Tags: macos, xcode6

i'm developing a mac app that requires email access

here's the code i've tried on ios

```
-(IBAction)Contact us:(id)sender {
//Email Subject
NSString *emailTitle = @"";
//Email Content
NSString *messageBody = @"";
//Email Address
NSArray *toRecipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@mandarin-espeak.com"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

}
```

how can i do it on a mac app to open default email client

Comment: You'll find your answer here.. [Send Email - Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396229/send-email-cocoa)

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS you can easily send e-mails like this:

```
class SendEmail: NSObject {
    static func send() {
        let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)!
        service.recipients = ["abc@dom.com"]
        service.subject = "Vea software"

        service.performWithItems(["This is an email for auto testing through code."])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SendEmail.send()
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without having to open mail? I'd like to send emails in the background.

Comment: New to Apple? Apple will, whenever possible, prevent your software from doing stuff in background. E-mails are taken seriously: the user will always have the final word and it is the user who must press "send" if you would like to take advantage of Apple's built-in Email sending service.

If you'd like to send them automatically in background, you'll probably need to implement the client-side SMTP protocol in your app. Depending of your usage, that'd be a huge overkill and might not be compliant with Apple's guidelines, so be careful if you take that path.

Comment: Nah, I've been programming MacOSX and AppleScript's for a while, I'm building an app that will only run on one machine so I don't need to be concerned with sandboxing for any release. I'm just going to run an AppleScript that calls Outlook from my app and sends the email. I guess I could also command line it but this machine is not set up as a mail server and I was looking for a quick solution.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. Maybe I should post it to help others and get some constructive criticism on the code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with an AppleScript solution. This is a one off app, not for the store, so I turned sandboxing off. I also added `Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description` to the `info.plist` and in the `Hardened Runtime` under `Signing and Capabilities` checked `Apple Events`

My email code, shouldn't be too hard to pan out my unique stuff:

```
func emailUser(_ thisUser:NSManagedObject) {

        let dictSIPResponse = checkSIPforAppIdentifier("com.microsoft.Outlook")
        if let bIsSIPEnabled = dictSIPResponse["isSIPEnabled"] as? Bool, let strSIPMessage =  dictSIPResponse["sipMessage"] as? String{
            if bIsSIPEnabled {
                if let thisWriter = thisUser as? Writer, let strEmailAddress = thisWriter.email {
                    let outlookScript = """
                            if application "Outlook" is running then
                                tell application "Outlook"
                                    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Hooray for automation"}
                                    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Steve Suranie", address:"steven.suranie@xandr.com"}}
                                    send newMessage
                                end tell
                            end if
                        """

                    var out: NSAppleEventDescriptor?

                    if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: outlookScript) {
                        var errorDict: NSDictionary? = nil
                        out = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)

                        if let error = errorDict {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }

                }
            } else {
                print(strSIPMessage)
            }
        }

    }
```

Before trying to email with the AppleScript I check to ensure the permissions have been set:

```
func checkSIPforAppIdentifier(_ sipIdentifier:String) -> Dictionary<String, Any> {

        var dictSIPResponse = [String:Any]()
        var targetAppEventDescriptor = NSAppleEventDescriptor(bundleIdentifier: sipIdentifier)
        var status = AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget(targetAppEventDescriptor.aeDesc, typeWildCard, typeWildCard, true);

        switch (status) {
                case -600: //procNotFound
                    dictSIPResponse["isSIPEnabled"] = false
                    dictSIPResponse["sipMessage"] = "Not running app with id \(sipIdentifier)"
                    break;

                case 0: // noErr
                    dictSIPResponse["isSIPEnabled"] = true
                    dictSIPResponse["sipMessage"] = "SIP check successfull for app with id \(sipIdentifier)"
                    break;

                case -1744: // errAEEventWouldRequireUserConsent
                    // This only appears if you send false for askUserIfNeeded
                    dictSIPResponse["isSIPEnabled"] = false
                    dictSIPResponse["sipMessage"] = "User consent required for app with id \(sipIdentifier)"
                    break;

                case -1743: //errAEEventNotPermitted

                    dictSIPResponse["isSIPEnabled"] = false
                    dictSIPResponse["sipMessage"] = "User didn't allow usage for app with id \(sipIdentifier)"

                    // Here you should present a dialog with a tutorial on how to activate it manually
                    // This can be something like
                    // Go to system preferences > security > privacy
                    // Choose automation and active [APPNAME] for [APPNAME]


                default:
                    break;
            }

        return dictSIPResponse

    }
```